# How to optimize count based on multiple where conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
foo_count = Foo.where(some_id: @some_id, :bar_val => 100).count
```

Is this the best way to count objects which match a certain criteria or could this be optimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `@some_id` is referring to an ActiveRecord association (ie `SomeObject` has_many `Foo`), you could do something like this:

```
foo_count = @some_object.foos.where(:bar_val => 100).count
```